# How to load razor page before it's done rendering?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a table of records in `Index.cshtml`, once a user clicks on a record to view the details it will take them to `Details.cshtml`.

The issue is, there is a lot of data being pulled and the page has a slow response time. I would like to add a loading spinner but the page doesn't switch, it just stays on Index.cshtml until all the data is loaded from the OnGet in Details.cshtml then it switches the page fully loaded/rendered.

How do I get my application to jump to Details.cshtml once a user clicks a record, have my loading spinner display, and then finish loading page. I don't want the user to be sitting waiting at the Index page.

Index.cshtml

```
<a asp-page="/Details" asp-route-id="@Person.id">Select</a>
```

****Details.cshtml.cs,****

```
//simplified  

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
 var data = await _dataService.GetData(id); 
 return Page(); 
}
```

Comment: Dont load the data in `OnGet` then. Defer it to an XHR and call it `onGetDataAync()`. This way you can render your skeleton and hydrate it with data afterwards.

Comment: The long loading time seems like the main issue here.  Seems like a good case for pagination.  You could also use various methods for opening a modal-type dialog for details, JS (handle the click using Javascript) and non-JS (set the link's target to an iframe or do something simple like setting title to details which would show on hover.) If it's a standard GET (and not a GET from JS) you still need to wait for a standard page load before any JS fires.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a partial page and js,use js to call the partial page,and pass the id to it,then use `await _dataService.GetData(id);`:

Details.cshtml:

```
<div id="content"></div>
@section Scripts{ 

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'Index2?id=@Model.ID',
            }).done(function (result) {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = result;
            })
        })
    </script>
}
```

Details.cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
public int ID { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
 ID = id;
 return Page(); 
}
```

Index2.cshtml.cs:

```
public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
        {
            var data = await _dataService.GetData(id); 
            return Page();
        }
```

**Update:**
If you don't want to return the layout elements,try to add the following code to Index2.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout=null; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this but why create another razor page (Index2) to handle to ajax? Can I not just make another page handler in Details.cshtml.cs? Also if i return Page() will that return even the layout elements or just my Details page? I'm going to test it out but figured I'd ask in case I get a quicker response than testing. Thanks!

Comment: `Can I not just make another page handler in Details.cshtml.cs?`If you use this,you still needs to pass `Index2` in the handler,and needs to pass id to it.Or you cannot return the html of Index2 in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed in the following manner.

**Step 1: are you sure that your data access code is optimized ?**

What can you do here:

- check the query you are actually doing. Are you using an index ? If not, try to add an index and check if it helps in reducing the execution time. You can use the database tooling to check the actual query execution plan (I don't know what kind of database you are using, but any commonly used professional database offer some sort of tooling to check a query execution plan).
- are you loading the minimum amount of fields that you need ? Sometimes people tend to write something like `SELECT * FROM MyTable` and end up loading all the 35 fields they have defined in `MyTable` when they actually need 2 or 3 of them.
- have you considered caching the query result ? I would do this only after trying to optimize the query, in the way explained above. Sometimes data can be cached because they don't become stale, or it is acceptable to have stale data. This depends on your use case of course. Some other times it is possible to cache data and invalidate the cache when data changes and become stale.

**Step 2: do you really need to show all the entire result set to the user ?**

Sometimes we create web pages where we show 1000 record of data to the user. Most of the times this is useless: how many times you navigated to the second page of results of a Google search ? I mean that you can consider to show your users only the first 10 items and offer them a load more button, or a pagination system or a way to filter their search in order to reduce the result set.

**Step 3: are you doing a lot of joins to load your data ?**

Maybe you need to prepare a read model which is exactly 1:1 with the data that you need to show in your view, so that you can run a plain and simple query on it (no joins at all) and you are able to fetch the data in a quick and simple way. Consider exploring the CQRS architectural pattern.

**Step 4: you can evaluate to load the data client side, in order to
quickly show something to the user and let the actual data to load lazily, in the user browser**.

To do this, you need to move a great amount of your page rending to the client, by using an AJAX request and some Javascript.

If all of your application is rendered server side and you are working from a Razor Page or an MVC project, I would avoid to do this. It's a complete different paradigm and, in any case, you need to optimize your data access code and review the amount of data that you want to load for the user.

In my opinion Step 1 and Step 2 are enough in the majority of cases.

Comment: I am using MS Sql Server and as of right now it's a stored procedure that is returning multiple result sets, about 6, so I'm sure that's the hold up. No joins. I haven't worked with TSQL enough to know how to optimize it more than it is, and yes I am returning everything I need to display. Thanks for the information!